# Android SQLITE database and spinner

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

Hi geek am new to android,actually i need the code for 
selected data to be added into spinner from Db,in spinner when i select an item it should show me the details of column from Db.
fields of the DB:
1.Bank name
2.account number
3.amount details
4.Task
Note:(Bank name to be added to spinner,when i select a bank name in spinner it should show me the account number,amount details and task in a list view).

Comment: Have you implemented anything for SQLite? Are you able to create custom listview for displaying such details?

Comment: yes i got output to spinner and then i need the Account number,amount details and task in list view....

Answer (score 0):

Selected data to be added into spinner from Db ->

you have to have a bit experience in SQLite or any other compatible database with android.. If its SQLite, you have to get a List of objects form the Database. (There are severla ways to do it. If you want I can help you about this).

If you can come up with a List, then you can load it to a Spinner like this.

```
public void fillSpinner(Spinner yourSpinner, List yourListFromDB) {
    ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourListFromDB);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    yourSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}
```

Comment: yes i got output to spinner and then i need the Account number,amount details and task in list view....

Comment: what did you load to your Spinner, is is just Strings of Bank Names or Bank objects? If you add Bank objects, you can get the Id of a particular bank and query your other details through that. if you can tell me in details about your approach it's easier to help...

Comment: hi geeks am creating a project to generate an random number and that will show in a edit text.
am using one edit text and two button (one for generate random number and another one for refresh ) am get the random number in edit text and i want to refresh dat... can u help me and send me the code for dat....